# SAPUI5 Send oData Request to Changeset

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I would like to send a batch request to the changeset in the backend from my UI5 application. I did the following:

I created an Entity in my segw service. In the "changeset_begin" method I set the cv_defer_mode to true for my Entity.

In the frontend I tried to send a call to the backend. But somehow it doesnt work and I cant set a breakpoint in the ChangeSet. Are my syntax wrong? Thank you very much!

```
        oDataModel.create("/MyEntitySet", { // in a loop, values are changed
            properties: {
                Key: item[i].getKey(),
                Salesorder:"347854"
                Department: "HR"
            }
        });


        oDataModel.submitChanges({ // executed after loop
            success: function (oData) {
                oDataModel.refresh();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23methods/createEntry) the method you are looking for is `createEntry`.

> Creates a new entry object which is described by the metadata of the entity type of the specified sPath Name. For each created entry a request is created and stored in a request queue. **The request queue can be submitted by calling `submitChanges`**